# Lambda Docker Build GO - RIE:no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, aws-lambda

Iam trying to build a lambda docker image for a golang function, after reading through the docs on AWS I copied the example dockerfile provided using the recommended base image of `lambda/provided:al2`

Changed the first base image that provides the golang runtime to match local golang runtime of 1.19.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.19 as build
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2

COPY --from=build /app/main ./main
ENTRYPOINT [ "./main" ]
```

After a successful build I run this command (*from aws docs*):
`docker run -d -v ~/.aws-lambda-rie:/aws-lambda -p 9000:8080 --entrypoint /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie go-test-image:latest ./main`

```
Which returns the error: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie": stat /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

but reading the docs the AWS provided image already includes the `aws-lambda-rie`

I have also tried to run:
`docker run  -p 9000:8080  go-test-image:latest`

which returns errors of missing lambda environment variables:

```
 expected AWS Lambda environment variables [_LAMBDA_SERVER_PORT AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API]
```

Any ideas of what I am missing on this, or cause of these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unable to start container process: exec: "/aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie": stat /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie: no such file or directory: unknown.`

Start with making your Docker image self-contained and runnable without needing the `aws-lambda-rie` externally: add it directly to your Docker image (instead of mounting it at runtime at `/aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie`):

```
FROM golang:1.19 as build
WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o main

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2

# Install aws-lambda-rie
RUN curl -Lo /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie && chmod +x /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
COPY --from=build /app/main ./main
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie", "./main" ]
```

Then run the container without mounting the `aws-lambda-rie` from the host:

```bash
docker run -p 9000:8080 go-test-image:latest
```

---

As illustration, you can [see here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en&u=https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/ask/sof/107415124&client=webapp) another way to add `aws-lambda-rie`

```
ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
COPY entry.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /entry.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entry.sh" ]
```

That relies on [Dockerfile ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) supporting a URL as source.

---

To get back to the proposed Dockerfile, using `ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie", "./main" ]` sets the default behavior of the container. It means when the container starts, it will run the command `/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie ./main`.

- `/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie`: That is the Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE). Its purpose is to mimic the AWS Lambda environment locally. That tool intercepts the Lambda runtime API calls and allows your function code to run as if it is inside an actual Lambda environment.
- `./main`: That is the actual compiled Go binary (your Lambda function) that you want to run.

So, when you start the container, RIE starts up and then runs your `./main` binary within the emulated Lambda environment. That way, you can make HTTP requests to `localhost:8080/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations` to test your Lambda function as if it was being triggered in the actual AWS environment.

Comment: Huh, does AWS really not release a valid base image for local testing? This setup seems unfortunately awkward.

Comment: @flakes I agree: this answer is just for testing, expanding on the Dockerfile proposed by the OP.

Comment: @flakes this is the image provided by AWS for testing https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html in this case did not work as expected. using the Amazon Linux 2 base image.

Comment: @VonC this solution worked thanks for the clarity, yet there was a few additional steps, the docs I linked in the above link from AWS seemed to not need these steps, if you could provide what exactly I missed here.

Comment: @PHPNoob Did you use https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/provided as base image? Because in your question, you do a `docker run` of an image you have built, and that image did not use `lambda/provided` as its base image.

Comment: @PHPNoob Plus, the Lambda base images might not include RIE by default, because the RIE is not needed when running in the actual AWS Lambda environment: it is a tool meant specifically for *local* testing.

Comment: No not as the base image, as their documentation explains to do a multi-stage build here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html#:~:text=Creating%20an%20image%20from%20the%20provided.al2%20base%20image

Comment: With that, are you proposing to avoid the over head and to build directly to the the Amazon Linux lambda base image instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254912/discussion-between-vonc-and-exception-thrown).

Answer (score 1):

> but reading the docs the AWS provided image already includes the aws-lambda-rie

It is included, but seems to be referenced incorrectly in the docs.

Digging around inside the image, there is `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` which references `/usr/local/bin/aws-lambda-rie`.

You can use that directly as the docs suggest.

Edit: The below does not work. `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` references `/var/runtime/bootstrap`, which I expect is only included in [AWS base images for specific languages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#runtimes-images-lp). As we're using Go, the compiled executable is the runtime.

<s>, or instead, make use of `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` as your entrypoint:</s>

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/lambda-entrypoint.sh", "./main" ]
```

`/lambda-entrypoint.sh` detects when your container is running locally and makes use of the RIE. If your container is running in the cloud, it executes the Lambda runtime bootstrap script directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator in your image, like suggested in the accepted answer above, you can download it locally and mount it in the running container, as described in the [AWS documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html).

These commands can be used to download locally:

```
LAMBDA_RIE_URL="https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie"
## or if using arm64:
# LAMBDA_RIE_URL="https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie-arm64"
mkdir -p ~/.aws-lambda-rie
pushd ~/.aws-lambda-rie
curl -Lo aws-lambda-rie "${LAMBDA_RIE_URL}"
chmod +x aws-lambda-rie
popd
```

Then you can use the command from the [AWS documentation indicated by the OP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html) and it will work:

```
docker run -d -v ~/.aws-lambda-rie:/aws-lambda -p 9000:8080 --entrypoint /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie go-test-image:latest ./main
```